Cardinality of the logical consequence relation
The Question
I'm wondering — how many valid inferences are there in classical propositional logic?
Put another way, what is the cardinality of the logical consequence relation in classical propositional logic? It seems that the answer is $\mathfrak{c}$ (the continuum), but I'm a bit confused here.
My Attempt
Here's my attempt at an aswer. The language I use is $\mathcal{L} = \{p_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\neg, \vee\}$.
$\mathcal{L}$ is countably infinite.
The set of well-formed formulas, $Form$, is defined recursively as usual.
The cardinality of $Form$ is also countably infinite: $|Form| = \aleph_0$.
We have valuation functions $v:Form\longrightarrow \{1,0\}$.
We define the logical consequence relation the usual way:
Def. ($\vDash$) Logical consequence is a relation $\vDash \;\subseteq\; \mathcal{P(Form) \times Form}$ such that:
$\langle \Gamma, \varphi \rangle \in \;\vDash$ $\;$iff$\;$ for all valuations $v$, if $v(\gamma) = 1$ for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$, then $v(\varphi) =1$ .
Claim 1. The logical consequence relation, $\vDash$, has at most $\mathfrak{c}$-many elements.
Note that $|\mathcal{P}(Form) \times Form| = \text{max}(\mathfrak{c}, \aleph_0) = \mathfrak{c}$.
Since $\vDash \;\subseteq\; \mathcal{P}(Form) \times Form$, the cardinality of $\vDash$ is at most $\mathfrak{c}$. That is, $\vDash$ has at most uncountably many elements. $\Box$
Claim 2. The logical consequence relation, $\vDash$, has at least $\mathfrak{c}$-many elements.
Proof.
Consider the set of propositional tautologies, $Taut = \{\varphi : \varphi \in Form, \text{ and } v(\varphi)=1 \;\text{for all valuations}\; v\}$.
We see that $Taut \subseteq Form$.
For each $p_n \in \{p_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ there is a corresponding tautology $p_n \vee \neg p_n$.
Thus, since there are countably many $p_n$, there are countably many tautologies of the form $p_n \vee \neg p_n$. Let $R = \mathcal{P}(Form) \times Taut$.
But since the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(Form)$ is $\mathfrak{c}$, $|\mathcal{P}(Form)|=\mathfrak{c}$, also $|R| = |\mathcal{P}(Form) \times Taut| = \mathfrak{c}$.
By definition of $Taut$ and logical consequence, clearly $R \;\subseteq\; \vDash$.
So, the cardinality of $\vDash$ is at least $\mathfrak{c}$. $\Box$
My Answer. The logical consequence relation, $\vDash$, has continuum-many elements.
Proof. By Claim 1, $|\vDash|$ is at most $\mathfrak{c}$. By Claim 2, $|\vDash|$ is at least $\mathfrak{c}$. Hence, $|\vDash|= \mathfrak{c}$. That is, there are $\mathfrak{c}$-many valid inferences in classical propositional logic. $\Box$
Really...?
This feels off, however.
Would anyone be kind enough to point out any mistakes in my argumentation, or point me to relevant literature?
Many thanks in advance.

Throughout, when you wrote "uncountable", you meant "cardinality continuum". "Uncountable" just means "not countable", i.e. greater than $\aleph_0$. It does not refer to a single cardinality. So the phrase "at most uncountable" is meaningless. Otherwise, your reasoning is correct.

This is correct. A simpler way to see this is to note that given a subset $S$ of $ \mathcal{P}(Form)$, we must have $S\models p_{1} \lor \neg p_{1}$. Now, since they are uncountably many subsets there are uncountably many logical consequences. If you just want to show that there are uncountably many elements in a set you don’t need to show that there can be “atmost uncountable” since that’s a triviality. What you really have done is bounded the cardinality by $\mathfrak{c}$ and then shown that it must be exactly $\mathfrak{c}$. But that’s much stronger than just saying that it has uncountably many elements.

Thank you for your answer, and especially for the note on bounding the cardinality. Is there a typo in you answer, though? Did you mean that we must have $S \vDash p_1 \vee \neg p_1$? (You currently have a conjunction there.)
